# (Scheme) Unbound Variable when copy-pasting code

Tags: macos, emacs, scheme

I'm copying the following Scheme code into a buffer file on emacs from a pdf:

```
(define (plural wd)
  (if (equal? (last wd) ’y)
    (word (bl wd) ’ies)
    (word wd ’s)))
```

The initial formatting is as a long string, and I manually edit it to the format seen above. The file loads, but when I use the function I get the error:

```
*** Error:
unbound variable: |’y|
Current eval stack:
__________________
0    (equal? (last wd) |’y|)
1    (if (equal? (last wd) |’y|) (word (bl wd) |’ies|) (word wd |’s|))
```

When I manually type this code and load the file, however, the function runs no problem.

In what way is the pasting/editing of the code messing with the formatting of the code?

Is there a proper way to copy-paste code into a file? I tried formatting the code in a text editor before pasting into the buffer, but that didn't work either.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: You need to replace the curly quotes with ASCII single quotes.

Comment: Whoever created the PDF let it do "smart quotes".

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't know or notice that there are different quotes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It was already answered in the comments by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar), but this should enable you to complete your question, and help anybody else with the same problem in the future.

When you copy/pasted the code from the PDF, you did not copy a simple ASCII quote character `'`. Instead, you copied a "right single quotation mark" (unicode [U+2019](https://unicode-table.com/en/2019/)) `’`. As this is not a reserved character in Scheme, it can be used as an identifier, and so what you expected to be the quoted symbol `'y` was in fact the identifier `’y`. The error was caused by there being no binding for the variable `’y`.

A simple way of fixing this that does not required manually copying the code or fixing every quotation mark by hand is to find-and-replace `’` for `'` (as long as you don't expect any `’` characters in your strings).

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I was puzzled by that error, and you make it clear how it came about.

Comment: @user9969550 Be aware that this is now a common problem when copying and pasting code, as numerous publishing systems these days implement 'intelligent' automatic conversion of apostrophes to curly quote characters, which introduces bugs when applied to code.  Because it can be hard to spot, the author of the document is generally unaware that the code they pasted has been broken in this way.

Comment: @user9969550 Incredibly, this is nowadays even a problem in Emacs.  You might want to customize the user option `text-quoting-style` and set it to `'grave` to ensure Emacs never messes with quotes.  Without that, if authors put a quote character into a docstring without using a special escape syntax (which was never previously needed), it gets converted to a different quote character, which of course means that example elisp in the docstring might cause errors.